# Frames of type double must be in the range of 0 to 1: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have a video and I have made a Sobel mask for it on MATLAB. Now I have to apply that Sobel mask on each frame of the video by reading each frame through `for` loop. The process is something like:

- Step 1: Reading frame.
- step 2: Converting it to grayscale using `rgb2gray`.
- Step 3: Converting it to double.

Here, after applying the mask when I try to write the frame on the resultant `video.avi` file, I get the following error:

> "Frames of type `double` must be in the range of 0 to 1"

What is wrong with my code?  The code I wrote is shown below:

```
vid = VideoReader('me.mp4');
frames = read(vid);
total = get(vid, 'NumberOfFrames');
write = VideoWriter('me.avi');
open(write);
mask1 = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; 1 2 1]; % Horizontal mask
mask2 = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1]; %Vertical Mask
for k = 1 : 125
    image = frames(:,:,:,k);
    obj = image;
    obj1 = rgb2gray(obj);
    obj2=double(obj1);
    for row = 2 : size(obj2, 1) - 1
        for col = 2 : size(obj2, 2) - 1
            c1 = obj2(row - 1, col - 1) * mask1(1 ,1);
            c2 = obj2(row - 1, col) * mask1(1 ,2);
            c3 = obj2(row - 1, col + 1) * mask1(1 ,3);
            c4 = obj2(row, col - 1)*mask1(2, 1);
            c5 = obj2(row, col)*mask1(2, 2);
            c6 = obj2(row, col + 1)*mask1(2, 3);
            c7 = obj2(row + 1, col - 1)*mask1(3,1);
            c8 = obj2(row + 1, col)*mask1(3,2);
            c9 = obj2(row + 1, col + 1)*mask1(3,3);
            c11 = obj2(row - 1, col - 1)*mask2(1 , 1);
            c22 = obj2(row, col - 1)*mask2(2, 1);
            c33 = obj2(row + 1, col - 1)*mask2(3, 1);
            c44 = obj2(row -1, col)*mask2(1, 2);
            c55 = obj2(row, col)*mask2(2 , 2);
            c66 = obj2(row +1, col)*mask2(2 , 3);
            c77 = obj2(row - 1, col + 1)*mask2(1 , 3);
            c88 = obj2(row, col +1)*mask2(2 , 3);
            c99 = obj2(row + 1, col + 1)*mask2(3 , 3);
            result = c1 + c2 + c3 +c4 +c5+ c6+ c7+ c8 +c9;
            result2 = c11 + c22 + c33 + c44 + c55 + c66 + c77 + c88 + c99;
            %result = double(result);
            %result2 = double(result2);
            rim1(row, col) = ((result^2+result2^2) *1/2);
            rim2(row, col) = atan(result/result2);
        end
    end
    writeVideo(write, rim2); %This line has the problem with rim2 as rim2 is the frame i'm trying to write on the video file.
end
close(write);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rim2` has range `[-pi/2, pi/2]` at the end, which is not compatible with the write function which expects [0,1] range. 
Convert it to `[0,1]` range using the `mat2gray` function, i.e.

```
writeVideo(write, mat2gray(rim2));
```

Your code will then work as expected (confirmed on my machine).

By the way, this doesn't affect your code, but presumably you meant to do `im2double(A)` rather than `double(A)`. The former produces a "proper" grayscale image in the range [0,1], whereas the latter simply converts your `uint8` image in the range [0,255] to `double` format (i.e. [0.0, 255.0]).

Comment: Thank you for your help, your suggestion of `mat2gray` worked. but i would like to understand the concept of all these things, so if you can give me a little time of you, i would like to have a chat with you.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to. Thank you for accepting my answer; I suspect you preferred it over @rayryeng's because it was short and went straight to the point (i.e. "fixed the problem"), which was my intent on contributing it; however rayryeng has given you an amazingly helpful breakdown of the issues and concepts involved in your task; you could at least acknowledge his effort by upvoting his contribution and spread some love (i.e. award reputation :) ) All the background information you need to understand the concepts involved is there nicely laid out. (ray: sorry, didn't mean to steal :p )

Comment: no no i didn't mean to disappoint or hurt @rayryeng. no doubt his suggestions are great but what i felt for me that, they were quite difficult for me to understand though i got some idea about his code (but could not understand all), and that was my problem because i'm not good in image-processing yet, so may be this is the reason i could not understand his code. and your suggestion was short so i just put it inside my code, that is why i asked for clearing my concepts about that.

Comment: You didn't steal anything at all.  Besides which, I have ~60k more reputation than you so you need some lol.  I have a tendency to ramble on and suggest things all in one post to make the answer more enriching, but at the detriment of boring the reader.  Nevertheless, good answer and I have upvoted.

Comment: ahahah, I know right, I do that too ... (also, thanks :p )

Answer (score 3):

The line of `rim2` inside your double `for` loop is using `atan`, which will generate values that are both positive and negative - from -pi/2 to +pi/2 exactly.  `rim2` is expected to have values that are only between `[0,1]`.  I can't figure out what exactly you're doing, but it looks like you're calculating the magnitude and gradient angle at each pixel location.  If you want to calculate the magnitude, you have to take the square root of the result, not simply multiply by `1/2`.  The calculation of the gradient (... or even the whole Sobel filter calculation...) is very funny.

I'll just assume this is working for your purposes so I'm not sure how to change the output of `rim2`for suitable display but perhaps you could scale it to the range of `[0,1]` before you write the video so that it's within this range.

Something like this would work before you write the frame:

```
rim2 = (rim2 - min(rim2(:))) / (max(rim2(:)) - min(rim2(:)));
writeVideo(write, rim2);
```

The above is your typical min-max normalization that is seen in practice.  Specifically, the above will ensure that the smallest value is 0 while the largest value is 1 per frame.  If you want to be consistent over all frames, simply add `pi/2` then divide by `pi`.  This assumes that the minimum is -1 and the maximum is +1 **over all frames** however.

```
rim2 = (rim2 + pi/2) / pi;
writeVideo(write, rim2);
```

---

However, I suspect you want to write the magnitude to file, not the angle.  Therefore, replace the video writing with `rim1` as the frame to write instead of `rim2`, then normalize after.  Make sure your gradient calculation is correct though:

```
rim1(row, col) = ((result^2+result2^2)^(1/2));
% or use sqrt:
% rim1(row, col) = sqrt(result^2 + result2^2);
```

Now write to file:

```
rim1 = (rim1 - min(rim1(:))) / (max(rim1(:)) - min(rim1(:)));
writeVideo(write, rim1);
```

---

However, if I can provide a method of efficiency, don't use `for` loops to compute the gradient and angle.  Use [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) and ensure you use the `'same`' flag or [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/images/imfilter.html) from the image processing toolbox to perform the filtering for you, then calculate the gradient and angle vectorized.  Also, convert to grayscale and cast your frame in one go in the main loop. I'll assume you have the image processing toolbox as having the computer vision toolbox (you have this as you're using a `VideoWriter` object) together with the image processing toolbox is what most people have:

```
vid = VideoReader('me.mp4');
frames = read(vid);
total = get(vid, 'NumberOfFrames');
write = VideoWriter('me.avi');
open(write);
mask1 = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; 1 2 1]; % Horizontal mask
mask2 = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1]; %Vertical Mask
for k = 1 : 125
    obj2 = double(rgb2gray(frames(:,:,:,k))); % New
    grad1 = imfilter(obj2, mask1); % New
    grad2 = imfilter(obj2, mask2); % New
    rim1 = sqrt(grad1.^2 + grad2.^2); % New
    rim2 = atan2(grad1, grad2); % New

    % Normalize
    rim2 = (rim2 - min(rim2(:))) / (max(rim2(:)) - min(rim2(:)));
    writeVideo(write, rim2); 
end
close(write);
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, actually i have been given a task in which i had to make a video of myself and i have to find the edges of my body in each frame. for this purpose, the frame must be a grayscale image so i have converted it with rgb2gray, now, if i do not use double, i get an error with "atan" as atan do not accept unit8 image as input parameters. so i have converted it to double. after all these processing, i have to write that edges found frame to a new video file.

Comment: @MehranKhan Ah I see.  OK, so it looks like your horizontal and vertical gradients are OK... and you want to find the angle.  I would suggest you use `atan2` instead as it respects what quadrant your points in space lie on.  Try my edit and see if it works.  The min-max normalization should be suitable for your purposes.... but I think you simply want to calculate the magnitude, not the angle.

Comment: if i do not calculate the angel, it does not produces the desired result but it works good with angel calculation. i want to show you the image but i don't know how to post image here.

Comment: thanks again for your help, i exactly know about imfilter and other methods and i have worked with them. but i'm supposed to do it in such a way as i'm doing it because this is a task assigned by my teacher. actually we are learning how to create the mask by ourselves and use it on the images and videos.

Comment: yeah i'm trying your way out. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No worries. If it works, let me know and when you're ready, consider accepting my answer to let the community know you no longer need help. Thanks!